# How can I properly install Nvidia driver and toolkit and samples?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

Working on ubuntu 16.04 I want to install `sudo sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run` or basically make that command setup all the 3 mentioned in my question, what I first did :

1- ctrl+alt+f1

2-`sudo service lightdm stop`

3-`sudo init 3`

4-`sudo sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run`

It gave me I failed message for the driver so I checked the log and found that Nouveau is conflicting with Nvidia's installation process, to disable it I did :

5-Created a file:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

6-It has this content :

blacklist nouveau

options nouveau modeset=0

7-`sudo update-initramfs -u`
to regenerate the kernel

8-`reboot`

Then I repeated the steps 1 to 4 and got this error: the driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source please make sure that the kernel source and packages are installed correctly or pass the location in a '--kernel-source-path'.

Now using command 7 I got the regenerating in /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic and trying the command `uname -r` I got `4.13.0-36-generic` so the kernel should be there I guess? how do I continue from there to finish my installation and these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you confirm you have pre-installation dependencies installed (check §2.3 and §2.4 of [Cuda Installation Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux.pdf))?

If so, you just have to follow step by step [Quick Start Guide](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf) ( starting §4.1.5.2 in your case)

Looks like you miss kernel header, xorg.conf generation and variables links ($PATH...) steps.

Comment: I have referred to the first part of your answer and apparently I don't have the pre-installation dependencies installed, I got an error for `gcc version` and for `sudo yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-headers-$(uname -r)` I got  `yum` command not found, any further guidance regarding the commands I should use to solve these 2 issues.

Comment: the sections 2.3 2.4 don't have a distribution mentioned or such, not even a guidance to how to execute that step differently per distributions.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install gcc` apparently I have the newest version 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 but when I type `gcc version` I get an error, no such file or directory.

Comment: Oh ok then apparently I have both as that last command gave the output linux-headers-1.13.0-37-generic is already installed, then I switched to the second link in your answer precisely this part `Reboot into runlevel 3 by temporarily adding the number "3" and the word
"nomodeset" to the end of the system's kernel boot parameters.`  I didn't quite understand the command I should un, before I just did `sudo init 3`

Comment: ok so I didn't replace quiet splash with 3 nomodeset instead I added it in front of ro quiet splash because your way just didn't wok which lead me to do some more digging, but the screen is just stuck on the Ubuntu logo.

Comment: That's normal if you have no GUI when changing "quiet splash" into " 3 nomodeset". You have to use CTRL+ALT+F1 to open a terminal and launch your commands. I suggest you give a try with the 4.2.1.1. Debian installer, that requires less tweaks.